# How to determine the constants for the variables in the slice function while plotting a SVM model

Tags: r

I am trying to plot the SVM model using the plot function, however I am unable to decide the constants that I need to input for the variables.

I have tried removing the factor variables before plotting the data, however I am still getting an error

> Error in [.data.frame(expand.grid(lis), , labels(terms(x))) :
>   undefined columns selected

The data is -

```
head(data,5)
      credit.policy            purpose int.rate installment log.annual.inc   dti fico days.with.cr.line revol.bal revol.util inq.last.6mths delinq.2yrs pub.rec
    1             1 debt_consolidation   0.1189      829.10       11.35041 19.48  737          5639.958     28854       52.1              0           0       0
    2             1        credit_card   0.1071      228.22       11.08214 14.29  707          2760.000     33623       76.7              0           0       0
    3             1 debt_consolidation   0.1357      366.86       10.37349 11.63  682          4710.000      3511       25.6              1           0       0
    4             1 debt_consolidation   0.1008      162.34       11.35041  8.10  712          2699.958     33667       73.2              1           0       0
    5             1        credit_card   0.1426      102.92       11.29973 14.97  667          4066.000      4740       39.5              0           1       0
      not.fully.paid
    1              0
    2              0
    3              0
    4              0
    5              0


str(data,5)
'data.frame':   9578 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ credit.policy    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ purpose          : chr  "debt_consolidation" "credit_card" "debt_consolidation" "debt_consolidation" ...
 $ int.rate         : num  0.119 0.107 0.136 0.101 0.143 ...
 $ installment      : num  829 228 367 162 103 ...
 $ log.annual.inc   : num  11.4 11.1 10.4 11.4 11.3 ...
 $ dti              : num  19.5 14.3 11.6 8.1 15 ...
 $ fico             : int  737 707 682 712 667 727 667 722 682 707 ...
 $ days.with.cr.line: num  5640 2760 4710 2700 4066 ...
 $ revol.bal        : int  28854 33623 3511 33667 4740 50807 3839 24220 69909 5630 ...
 $ revol.util       : num  52.1 76.7 25.6 73.2 39.5 51 76.8 68.6 51.1 23 ...
 $ inq.last.6mths   : Factor w/ 28 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ delinq.2yrs      : Factor w/ 11 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ pub.rec          : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ not.fully.paid   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...

library(e1071)

?svm

data <-  read.csv("loan_data.csv", header = T,  stringsAsFactors = F)

str(data)


# data <-  as.factor(data[ , c('inq.last.6mths', 'delinq.2yrs', 'pub.rec','not.fully.paid','credit.policy')])



for (i in 11:14) {
    if (is.numeric(data[, i])) {
     data[,i] = as.factor(data[,i]) 

    }

  }

str(data)  


for (i in 1) {
  if (is.numeric(data[,i])) {
    data[,i] = as.factor(data[, i])

  }

}

library(caTools)

split <-  sample.split(data$not.fully.paid, 0.7)

train <- subset(data,  split == T)
test <- subset(data, split==F)

fmodel <- svm(not.fully.paid ~ . , data = train)

print(mymodel)

tuning_para <-  tune(svm, not.fully.paid ~ . , data= train , kernel = 'radial',ranges = list(cost = c(0.1,1, 3), gamma = c(0.5,1)))

summary(tuning_para)

fmodel <-  svm(not.fully.paid ~ . , data = train, cost = 0.1, gamma = 0.5, kerel ='radial')

col <- c( "purpose","int.rate", "installment", "log.annual.inc" , "dti", "fico","days.with.cr.line", "revol.bal", "revol.util")


# plotting the model  - UNABLE TO DECIDE THE CONSTANTS THAT NEED TO BE 
#DENOTED TO THE VARIABLES 

# keeping only numeric variables
train1 <-  train[c(3:10, 14)]

plot(fmodel, data = train1, int.rate ~ revol.util, slice = list(installment = 1, log.annual.inc = 2 , dti =3 , fico =4 , days.with.cr.line =5 , revol.bal =6  ))
```

The error that I am getting when I use the plot function is

> Error in [.data.frame(expand.grid(lis), , labels(terms(x))) : enter
>   code here   undefined columns selected

Please suggest the best values for the parameters in the slice function under plot.